# javascript not rendering what it's supposed to in rails 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm new to this but from what I can tell there shouldn't be any issues. I have a page where a user can upload photos and delete them. Both of these functions work fine, the photos will upload and delete, but I'm trying to get the photos to delete with javascript and the page isn't rendering itself upon deletion like it's supposed to. This is the terminal output, and from what I can tell there's no problem:

```
Started DELETE "/equipment/5/photos/45" for ::1 at 2020-11-29 10:15:48 -0700
Processing by PhotosController#destroy as JS
Parameters: {"equipment_id"=>"5", "id"=>"45"}
Photo Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 
45], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:15:in `destroy'
Equipment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "equipment".* FROM "equipment" WHERE "equipment"."id" = ? 
LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:16:in `destroy'
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
Photo Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = ?  [["id", 45]]
↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
(31.7ms)  commit transaction
↳ app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
[paperclip] deleting 
/public/system/photos/images/000/000/045/original/Honda_hs1136_snowblower.jpg
[paperclip] deleting 
/public/system/photos/images/000/000/045/medium/Honda_hs1136_snowblower.jpg
[paperclip] deleting 
/public/system/photos/images/000/000/045/thumb/Honda_hs1136_snowblower.jpg
Rendering photos/destroy.js.erb
(0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."equipment_id" = ?  [["equipment_id", 
5]]
↳ app/views/photos/_photos_list.html.erb:1
Rendered photos/_photos_list.html.erb (Duration: 4.2ms | Allocations: 658)
Rendered photos/destroy.js.erb (Duration: 6.1ms | Allocations: 927)
Completed 200 OK in 69ms (Views: 12.0ms | ActiveRecord: 33.4ms | Allocations: 10559)
```

This is my photos controller:

```
def destroy
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
equipment = @photo.equipment

@photo.destroy
@photos = Photo.where(equipment_id: equipment.id)

respond_to :js

end
```

This is my destroy.js.erb file:

```
$('#photos').html("<%= j render 'photos_list' %>");
```

And this is my _photos_list.html.erb file:

```
<% if @photos.count > 0 %>
<br/><br/>

<div class="row">
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header preview">
        <%= image_tag photo.image.url() %>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="float-right">
          <%= link_to equipment_photo_path(photo.equipment_id, photo), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
          <% end %>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Like I said, the deleting of the photos is working, when I refresh the page the photos are gone, but obviously it should be doing this without refreshing.

Here is also the contents of photo_upload.html.erb where _photos_list.html.erb is rendered:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Photos
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <!-- PHOTO UPLOADS GO HERE -->

          <%= form_for @equipment, url: equipment_photos_path(@equipment), method: 'post', html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file text-babu">
                  <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Select Photos
                  <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
              <%= f.submit "Add Photos", class: "btn btn-form" %>
            </div>

          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="photos"><%= render 'photos/photos_list' %></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
  end
```

instead

```
respond_to :js
```

EDIT:
Can you please share view file where you render _photos_list.html.erb?

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't work, I've added the contents of photo_upload.html.erb which is where _photos_list.html.erb is rendered.